# rewriting url from example.php?id=2 to example/2

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, forum

Well, the title says it all. I'm creating a forum, and I need all the URLs to be like:

http://example.com/index (.php removed)

and for pages with $_GET variables to be like:

http://example.com/topic/this-is-the-topics-name

I'm not exactly sure on how to do this..

Comment: you could use this: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: How would I replace the %20 from the URL where spaces are suppose to be with hyphens?

Comment: `topic.php?id=2` to `/topic/2` might be doable with just htaccess, but to `/topic/the-name-of-the-topic-whose-id-is-2` is impossible with just htaccess, you need access to your database for that.

Comment: Ops, I messed up the name of the question, and really? How would I make it insert like that?

Comment: You do it from your php script, htaccess has zero idea what your database looks like, the `2` means as much to mod_rewrite as any character or any string.

Comment: Would it be like preg_replace($title, " ", "-"); ?